What is the tension of a string with forces on both sides and how does it relates with net force?
If two objects A and B are pulling on different side of the string with forces respectively $F_1$ and $F_2$. Now, what will be the tension of the string in both of the following cases:

The string is massless

The string has a mass


I know that the tension of each segment of the string is constant for a massless string. But I can't interrelate with the force body diagram of A, B and the rope. I would be delighted to see the force body diagram of the three objects. Also, what will be the net force of the system? Answer in both of the cases is required.
As a summary: I want to know the tension in the rope, force body diagram of the objects and the net force.

Anyone pls help me out

It does take time for Stack Exchange answers to accumulate.  As a general policy, people asking questions are recommended to wait 24 hours before accepting an answer, in case a better one comes along.  You can use that rule of thumb to extrapolate how long it will take to get a satisfactory answer for your question.  Some answers come quicker than others (we're particularly good at marking a question as a duplicate quickly, which typically gets you that answer rapidly).

If the net force acting on the massless string was non-zero, mathematically that would mean the acceleration of the string is undefined, i.e., it could have any value. And yet, the string may have a defined acceleration if it is part of a system that does have a net force on it. Examples are pulley systems where masses connected to massless strings are accelerating.
See FIG A below shows a massless string.
On the other hand, a string with mass can have a net force acting on it. See FIG B.
The tension in an infinitesimal section of the string with mass will vary along the string from $F_1$ at the left to $F_2$ at the right. See FIG C where the tension is $F$ for an infinitesimal piece of string in the middle of the string cut in half and equals the average of the two applied forces.
Hope this helps.


Because of massless string, I am not being able to visualise it. Theoretically, we can't apply two different forces at different ends?

@akifsami I have updated my answer for better clarity. See if that answers your question.



The string is massless


In the free body diagram illustrated below, the mass of the string is considered to be negligible in the context of the total system and it is convenient to idealise the sting as being massless:

Two rockets with different masses and different thrusts acting in opposite directions are connected by a string. We can calculate the total acceleration of the system as:  $$a = \frac{\text{Force}_{total}}{\text{Mass}_{total}} = \frac{-10+3}{4+10}= -\frac{1}{2} m/s^2$$
If we assume the string has already stretched to its equilibrium length and its length is no longer changing, then everything in the system is comoving and the acceleration is the same everywhere. This allows us to calculate the net force on each rocket. The net force of the rocket on left is $ma = 4\times -1/2 = -2N $ and the net force on the rocket on the right is $ma = 10\times-1/2=-5N$. The tension on the ends of the string is simply the difference between the thrust of the rocket and the net force on the rocket at a given end. It turns out that the forces on the ends of a massless string are always equal in magnitude and opposite in direction.


The string has a mass


In the next scenario the string is treated as having all its mass concentrated at the centre for ease of analysis (represented by the &kg circular mass):

Using the usual calculation, the acceleration of the complete system is $$a = \frac{\text{Force}_{total}}{\text{Mass}_{total}} = \frac{-10+3}{11+7+10}= -\frac{1}{4} m/s^2.$$
Every individual object including the string itself has this same acceleration of $0.25 m/s^2$. The interesting observation is that the two halves of the string have different tensions. This is a consequence of the accelerating string having mass.
Now let's see what happens when the mass of the string is divided up:

It can be seen that as the mass of the string is distributed along the string, the force at the extreme ends of the composite string remain the same, but between the distributed masses the tension is the average of the tension either side. Taken to the extreme, all the mass is distributed as infinitesimal pieces of mass everywhere along the length of the string and the tension along the string becomes a continuous gradient from one end to the other. This is an important distinction between massless strings and strings with mass. Unlike massless strings strings with mass can have different tensions at either end of the string and a tension gradient.
So far gravity has not been considered. If we have a massless string stretched horizontally between two solid walls, the string will be perfectly straight. If the string has mass, the string will be curved and the tension at the ends will greater than that of the massless string for the same normal force at the walls. Where things getting interesting with gravity is the vertical case. if the string is massless the tension at the top support end will be the same as the lower end connected to the load. If it has mass, once again the tension will vary along the length of the string. At the lowest point the tension will be equal to the attached load. At the highest point, the tension will be equal to the weight of the load plus the weight of the string itself.
In reality we cannot have a massless string. As the mass tends to zero the acceleration tends to infinite. Using a massless string out of context can produce unphysical conclusions, but with care can be a useful approximation. it is a bit like an infinitely rigid rod. Assuming such an object exists can results in contradictions to special relativity. They simply can't exist in reality. As such it is doesn't make much sense to define the net force on a massless string, but I guess there is a sense in which we can say it is $F = ma = 0 \times a = 0$

As a summary: I want to know the tension in the rope, force body
diagram of the objects and the net force.

For a string with mass, the net force on the string is $f = m a$, where m is the mass of the string and a is the acceleration of the whole system. a is calculated as Sa = F/M$, where F is the net force on the whole system (-7N in the above examples) and M is the mass of the total system including the mass of the string.

Thanks a lot man. I understand now

@akifsami You are very welcome. Glad to help :_)

You say the forces are pulling in opposite directions, so the net force on the string is $F_1 - F_2$, a non-zero value.
Then the acceleration of the string is $a = \frac{F_{net}}{m}$.  But if we assume the string is massless (or nearly massless), then the acceleration is humongous.
In reality, you would be unable to create the unequal forces on a light string in the first place.   It's like asking someone to push on a feather with a net force of 100N.  The feather accelerates so fast, the force can't develop.
